# Change the class of dynamic <li> elements created using InnerHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists, master-pages

I am creating a dynamic menu on my asp.net master page using UL and LI elements. The HTML part is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="ulMenu" runat="server">


</ul>
```

and here is the code I am using to populate LI elements in the above UL:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{        
     strInnerHTML += "<li runat='server' id='menu" + (i + 1).ToString() + "' class='hover'>";
}
ulMenu.InnerHtml = strInnerHTML;
```

Now what I want is to set the class of the selected LI element to **"hover active"** on the basis of the Page URL. And I am using the following code to do this:

```
HtmlGenericControl CurrMenu = (HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl(ControlId);
CurrMenu.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
```

In the above line the ControlId is the ID of selected LI element which is coming accurate as **"menu1", "menu2"** and so on.
The problem here is that LI element is not being found by the FindControl() function. It is returning null.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You cannot add `runat=server` to a string and expect it to work. You need "real" dynamic controls.

Comment: @VDWWD... can you tell me how to do that in my case ?

Comment: Use a `BulletedList` control. Or generate the complete html whenever the class changes.

Comment: @VDWWD can you give me any link or piece of code on the same... it would be more useful to me